# How to subscript/superscript and italicize x-axis labels?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to re-name the x-axis labels and would like to subscript/superscript few letters and numbers. For example, In FG(5,6)a I would like to italicize 'F' and would like to subscript/superscript 'a'. Likewise, I would like superscript/subscript and italicize '2' in KA(2,3)2, and a in LS(5,6)ab. Is there a way I can do this in R? Here is my code and output figure:

```
p <- ggbarplot(my_data_stack, x = "ind", y = "values", color = "ind", fill = "ind", 
                palette =c("blue", "green", "orange", "red", "black", "yellow"),
                width = 0.4, add = c("mean_se"))
p                
p +  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("a" = "SO", "b" = "KA(2,3)2", "c" = "FG(5,6)2", "d" = "FG(5,6)a", "e" = "LS(5,6)ab",
                                     "f" = "FG(1,5)f"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add subscripts/superscripts using [`expression()`](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/136237_170402e5f0b54561bf7605bdea98267a.html). Subscripts use `[]` and superscripts `^`.

So: "KA(2,3)2": `expression("KA"["2,3"]^2)`

Since there is a comma in the (2,3) you need to put it in quotes (or you can add the comma separately: `[2*","*3]`

Comment: If I would like to Italicize and superscript/subscript FG(1,5)f, should I have to use another expression  expression(~italic("FG")(2*","*3)[2])?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the tilde.